# Create GUI text above killed character

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am making a top down 2D game, and I am not sure how to place text above a character when then die.

I created a prefab with an empty game object which has a `GUIText` component attached to it. When my object dies I need to create the prefab object above it. When the object dies, the prefab is created in the correct spot, but the text is usually way off of the screen... Why is it doing that?

Here is the code:

```
void destroySelf(){
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(pointsTxt, transform.position / 0.1f, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    obj.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "+" + killPoints.ToString();
    Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUIText world positioning works in a 0..1 range. `transform.position = Vector3(0,0,0)` is the equivalent of bottom-left corner of the screen; `transform.position = Vector3(1,1,0)` is the top-right corner of the screen.

You've got the right idea using `WorldToScreenPoint`; now you just need to get the position values within the 0..1 range:

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
pos.x = pos.x / Screen.width;
pos.y = pos.y / Screen.height;
GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(pointsTxt, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

---

Alternatively, you could leave the GUIText's position as Vector3.zero (default from `Instantiate`), and alter its `pixelOffset` values instead:

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(pointsTxt) as GameObject;
GUIText text = obj.GetComponent<GUIText>();
text.pixelOffset.x = pos.x;
text.pixelOffset.y = pos.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TextMesh instead of GUIText like this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13625/procedurally-generate-a-textmesh.html

```
var textMesh = gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
textMesh.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
var meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
meshRenderer.material = textMesh.font.material;
textMesh.fontSize = 16;
textMesh.alignment = TextAlignment.Center;
textMesh.anchor = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
textMesh.text = "Hello";
```